# Hide and show `QGridLayout` with all included widgets

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to show or hide all widgets within a `QGridLayout`.

In the Python 3 code below appears no error message when triggering the toggle, but unfortunately the GUI does not change.

What is wrong in the code?

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._show_option_1 = True
        self._show_option_2 = True

        loadUi("mainwindow.ui", self)
        self.show()

    def toggle_option_1(self):
        self._show_option_1 ^= True
        if self._show_option_1:
            self.gridLayout_left.setEnabled(True)
            print("Show left layout")
        else:
            self.gridLayout_left.setEnabled(False)
            print("Hide left layout")

    def toggle_option_2(self):
        self._show_option_2 ^= True
        if self._show_option_2:
            self.gridLayout_right.setEnabled(True)
            print("Show right layout")
        else:
            self.gridLayout_right.setEnabled(False)
            print("Hide right layout")


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()

    main_window.pushButton_left.clicked.connect(main_window.toggle_option_1)
    main_window.pushButton_right.clicked.connect(main_window.toggle_option_2)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

mainwindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>555</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="locale">
   <locale language="English" country="UnitedKingdom"/>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_left">
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_left">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Option 1:</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="1">
       <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox_left"/>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="1">
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_right">
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_right">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Option 2:</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="1">
       <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox_right"/>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_left">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Toggle Option 1</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="1">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_right">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Toggle Option 2</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>555</width>
     <height>28</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QLayout.setEnabled()` changes layout state (sets it 'existing/not existing' more than really enabled/disabled'), but it's not touching underlying children controls.

To disable controls, you'll either have to loop over them, or use `QWidget` and place your layout inside of it.

If you have to use layout, and want to control underlying children, you can do something like this:

```py
for child in self.gridLayout_left.findChildren(QWidget):
   child.setEnabled(state)
```

With `QWidget` used instead of `QGridLayout`, your code gets a bit cleaner since disabling/hiding the widget, also disables/hides all underlying children, so your code becomes a bit simpler. Example:

```py
...
self.wgtContainer_left.setVisible(True) # To hide/show
self.wgtContainer_left.setEnabled(False) # To disable/enable
...
```